# MPTCP implementation..?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

After iOS7 launched, Multipath TCP allows for a connected device, such as an iPhone or iPad, to transmit data over multiple pathways simultaneously.Can any body explain how it can be implemented programitically or is it required to do anything programatically or does iOS take care everything u dont need to woorry about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS take care about everything. Classic TCP header is extended with MPTCP bits, which should be ignored by middleboxes between iOS and Siri servers. These bits tell both sides, all available IP address they can use and then MPTCP create connection between them.

MultiPath TCP is at this moment used only with Siri.

There exist [Linux implementation of MPTCP](http://mptcp.info.ucl.ac.be) you may be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Multipath TCP configuration is available for developers since iOS 11 . 
Developers using high level communication classes such as  **NSURLSession** , Can now choose between 3 different MPTCP modes , each suitable for different communication use case . 
Just set the **multipathServiceType** property in **NSURLSessionConfiguration** to a mode other than none.

Read about it : 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/improving_network_reliability_using_multipath_tcp